# Generate 4 distinct numbers that add up to a Random Generated Number

Tags: kotlin, distinct

I need this unit test to pass:

```
 @Test
    fun dividingIntoFour() {
        repeat(times = 100) {
            val randomNumber = Random.nextInt(from = 50, until = 90)
            val total = 100 - randomNumber
            val numberList = divideIntoFourDistinctNumbersThatAddUptoTotal(total = total)
            assert(numberList.sum() == total)
            assert(!numberList.contains(0))
            assert(numberList.all { it > 0 })
            assert(numberList.distinct().size == 4)
        }
    }
```

Passing cases:

The function correctly divides a total, which is 100 minus a random number between 50 and 90, into four distinct positive integers that sum up to the total, and this holds true for 100 iterations of the function.

Failing cases:

- The function returns a list containing 0.
- The function returns a list that does not contain exactly four
  distinct positive integers.
- The function returns a list of non-positive integers.
- The function returns a list of integers that do not add up to the
  given total.

This is as close as i've gotten - it either passes or hangs on the last while loop:

```
fun divideIntoFourDistinctNumbersThatAddUptoTotal(total: Int): List<Int> {
        var aTotal = total
        var first = (aTotal / 4..aTotal / 2).random()
        aTotal -= first
        var second = (3..aTotal - 3).random()
        while (second == first) {
            second = (3..aTotal - 3).random()
        }
        aTotal -= second
        var third = (3..aTotal).random()
        while (third == first || third == second) {
            third = (3..aTotal).random()
        }
        aTotal -= third
        var fourth = aTotal
        while (listOf(first, second, third, fourth).distinct().size != 4) {
            if (fourth == first) {
                fourth -= 1
                first += 1
            } else if (fourth == third) {
                fourth -= 1
                third += 1
            } else if (fourth == second) {
                fourth -= 1
                second += 1
            }
        }
        return listOf(first, second, third, fourth)
    }
```

ChatGpt has failed both on its openai website and through github copilot.

Comment: Can you provide an example of a pass and a fail in result terms?

Comment: Hi there, added to question. Cheers!

Comment: @ChristopherHall I think the title and the explanation contradict each other: _...Generate 4 distinct numbers that add up to a Total number between 50 and 90_ and _...divides a total, which is 100 minus a random number between 50 and 90.__

Comment: Cheers for that

Comment: @ChristopherHall One remark: When you do _fourth -= 1_ in the _while_ loop, you do not test for _fourth_ becoming zero.

Comment: Have you tried adding a `repeatCount` variable in the `while` loop that increments each time around, and after spinning its wheels 1000 times or whatever, logs the values of `total` and `first` etc so you can see what kind of number combinations are tripping it up? Also you said `total` can be *100 - 90* i.e. *10*, right? So `first` is a random number in `2..5`, and if it picks *5*, then `second` is picked from `3..2`, `third` is from either `3..0` or `3..-1`... is it meant to possibly produce invalid numbers like this?

Answer (score 0):

It seems a difficult task to solve this problem with an algorithm based on randomly getting one number, then randomly getting the second, and so on, because you will get an overproportional number of results that contain descending numbers. But if the sorting of the four numbers does not matter, then it will be fine.

If the function is not called to often in a row, then a simple search for the first solution in randomised lists might be the solution. This will probably be a bit slower than your algorithm (because of the three 'shufflings').

```
repeat(times = 100) {
  val total = (10..50).random()
  val ints = divideIntoFourDistinctNumbersThatAddUptoTotal(total = total)
  if (ints.sum() != total) println("Invalid total: $ints => $total")
  if (ints.contains(0)) println("Contains zero: $ints => $total")
  if (ints.distinct().size != 4) println("Not distinct: $ints => $total")
  println("$total -> $ints")
}

fun divideIntoFourDistinctNumbersThatAddUptoTotal(total: Int): List<Int> {

  val largestInt = total - (1 + 2 + 3)

  val ints1 = IntArray(largestInt) { it + 1 }.apply { shuffle() }
  val ints2 = IntArray(largestInt) { it + 1 }.apply { shuffle() }
  val ints3 = IntArray(largestInt) { it + 1 }.apply { shuffle() }

  for (i1 in ints1) {
    for (i2 in ints2) {
      if (i1 == i2) continue
      val sum12 = i1 + i2
      if (sum12 > total) continue
      for (i3 in ints3) {
        if (i1 == i3 || i2 == i3) continue
        val sum123 = sum12 + i3
        if (sum123 > total) continue
        val i4 = total - sum123
        if (i4 > 0 && i1 != i4 && i2 != i4 && i3 != i4) {
          return listOf(i1, i2, i3, i4).sorted()
        }
      }
    }
  }

  return emptyList()   // Only for when 'total' is smaller than 10 (1 + 2 + 3 + 4)

}
```

[Kotlin Playground](https://pl.kotl.in/xXxI-npbw)

Answer (score 0):

```
fun divideIntoFourDistintNumbersThatAddUpToTotal(total: Int): List<Int> {
    val max = total / 3 
    val list = (1..max).shuffled()
    val rand1 = list[0]
    val rand2 = list[1]
    val rand3 = list[2]
    val remainder = total - rand1 - rand2 - rand3

    val result = listOf(rand1, rand2, rand3, remainder)
    return if (result.distinct().size < 4 || result.firstOrNull { it <= 0} != null) divideIntoFourDistintNumbersThatAddUpToTotal(total)
    else result
}
```